# Is sorting a glBuffer (or placing sorted data into a GL buffer) sufficient for back-to-front rendering?

Tags: opengl, rendering

Currently I'm trying to handle actors that have alpha properties and got very messed up when I tried just drawing everything in one buffer. Right now, I can just draw the static 100% opaque scenery in one buffer since that doesn't change.

I don't know how you specifically render back-to-front properly. Do I just sort the vertices in the glBuffer I have and then push it off to the GPU?

Is this really just as trivial as sorting the vertices before placing them there? As in, the GPU will always draw vertices 0/1/2 for triangle 1, then 3/4/5 for triangle 2 (assuming it's set up this way), ...etc? If so then I assume I want to put the farthest away from me at the front of the buffer.

This seems like it should be an easy answer but different stack overflow questions seem to say different things which is leading me to confusion, so hopefully the answer is straightforward and easy.

EDIT: Define an actor to be a triangle, also assume that no intersections of triangles need to be worried about.

Comment: Define "actors". Drawing with alpha is always going to break if sorting is not perfect. If you have intersecting geometry or even intersecting single polygons, your rendering is going to break as sorting can not resolve this. For that you need "order independent transparency" methods that basically provide "per-pixel-sorting and -blending". There are a couple of methods, but [this approach](http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/papers/TransparencyI3D16/#abstract) looks quite useful.

Comment: @Bim I should have said that I don't have to worry about intersection cases, my goal is to understand how to render with alpha if I can sort by distance, or if I should try other approaches. While I'm interested in other approaches, if they're very brutal to code, it might be better for me to just sort and render. However, I don't know what way I should set up the buffer for proper alpha rendering. I should define an actor to be a flat triangle for this question as well.

Comment: Alpha blending with back-to-front sorted geometry is simple. Get a drawing surface with alpha, draw opaque geometry, enable blending, preferably use pre-multiplied alpha and draw transparent geometry.
Keep in mind this will make batching per shader/texture/etc. harder and, as I said, perfect sorting is hard and not always possible.

Comment: @Bim that is great to know, now the question is how to I force openGL to render back-to-front based on the data I put in the glBuffer, is it as simple as just writing the front triangles at the beginning of the buffer?

Comment: Yes. If the implementation adheres to the specs, it should. 
Read about transparency sorting [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting).
In your case you could also try to get away with [multiplicative or additive blending](http://www.openglsuperbible.com/2013/08/20/is-order-independent-transparency-really-necessary/), which requires you to render opaque geometry first, but no sorting of transparent geometry.